# Regular expression in PHP preg_replace() yields empty results

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm struggling with the regular expression syntax needed to simply transform this string:

```
posts/2012-03-16-23-07_an-awesome-post.md
```

into this string:

```
an-awesome-post
```

using the `preg_replace()` PHP function. Here's what I've got so far:

```
preg_replace('posts/[0-9-]*_([a-z-]*).md', '$1', 'posts/2012-03-16-23-07_an-awesome-post.md');
```

No dice. When I assign the result to a variable and `echo()` out that variable, I get nothing. My regex syntax is a bit rusty, but Googling around a bit makes me think that, at the very least, I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regex needs to be surrounded by delimiters.

Try  `'#posts/[0-9-]*_([a-z-]*).md#'` as your `$pattern` (using '#' as the delimiter).

Also, do you want that `.` to match a literal dot? Then it has to be escaped by a backslash, as in `\.`.

Comment: You are a god. Thanks! And for those interested in the resulting pattern, it's:
`'#posts/[0-9-]*_([a-z-]*)\.md#'`

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/posts\/[0-9-]*_([a-z-]*)\.md/', '$1', 'posts/2012-03-16-23-07_an-awesome-post.md');
```

Answer (score 1):

can you expect the string before "an-awesome-post" always to be the same lenght?
And the extension always to be .md?

If so, you can just count the number of chars before and after and cut them away.

For Example:

```
$string = substr($string, 23);
$string = substr($string, 0, -3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('#posts/[0-9-]*_([a-z-]*).md#i', '$1', 'posts/2012-03-16-23-07_an-awesome-post.md');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str="posts/2012-03-16-23-07_an-awesome-post.md";
$pattern=array('/([^_]*_)/','/\.md/');
$replacement=array('','');
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```

?>